# AWS Lambda loses connection to RDS intermittantly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

We have a lambda function that connects to an RDS instance. Sometimes the lambda function throws this error:
`'communication error', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')`
and 
`'communication error', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')`
Both error messges appear in quick succession. 
Subsequently the error resolves itself without any intervention. Both of them are in the same VPC. There is no set pattern when this communication failure occurs. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Err can you shot me the code that sounds like you've got a misconfigured call somewhere.

Comment: @MrkFldig thanks for looking into. But am not sure its related to db connection configuration. In such cases connection attempts would have failed every time. I am suspecting AWS's DNS resolution mechanism or their VPC. Here is the [code snippet](https://trinket.io/python3/eb55e1b838).

Comment: I keep seeing issues around the net relating to this, especially in python I can't for the life of me, I'm thinking a bug in the library your using is the culprit but thats a hunch, let me hit the google.

Comment: Do you have your Lambda in VPC with multiple subnets?

Comment: @MrkFldig same VPC. same AZ. Multiple subnets - yes. I did google before posting here :)

Comment: Hehe, just checking I wasn't saying you didn't - it's just odd it always comes up with Python, I've worked on API's with millions of requests in Node and never had it happen. Saying that the once a connection is open it doesn't get reopened if the container gets reused - looking at it I take it your doing the same sort of thing?

Comment: Heya how are you getting on with this, I've spoken to a few people and this whilst it keeps cropping up in Python never happens on any of the JS guys I've been speaking to so I'd be curious to replicate it?

Comment: Hey @MrkFldig, can you explain that in detail? I am afraid looking at this issue as python problem would take us completely off track. Would rather consider this a "software" problem :)